# Form validation issues in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am having a weird issue with my form validations. I have 4 inputs in my form and they are all being validated.

Everything works fine until it validates my last input field which is an email input field. I have two rules set on the email input field, `'rule' => 'notEmpty'` , `'rule' => 'email'`. The form validates and posts just fine when it only has to check for notEmpty rule but if an invalid email is found it does validate it but it doesn't post even after you input a valid email.

Here are some scenarios:
**One: User inputs valid entries for all the inputs**
Everything works fine, the form posts and the data is added to the database.

**Two: User inputs valid entries for all but the email input but then enters a valid emails in all inputs**
*Assuming that the user hits submit after only providing input for the first three fields*
Everything works fine after they input a valid email address on the first go, the form posts and data is added to the database.

**Three: User inputs valid entries for all except the email (provides an invalid email)**
It displays the error message but even after providing a valid email address it doesn't do anything. I notice that the page keeps reloading with the same data if you keep clicking the submit button.
*Also, the error message goes away if the submit button is clicked again after the initial click*

**Here is my Model:**

```
class Member extends AppModel
{
    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
        'Student_First_Name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
        'Student_Last_Name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
            ),
        'Student_Email' => array(
            'emailRule-1' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'last' => false
                ),
            'emailRule-2' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address.'
            ))
        );

}
```

**Here is the Controller:**

```
class MembersController extends AppController
{
    ...
    public function add()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $this->Member->create();

            if($this->Member->save($this->request->data))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Member has been added!');
                $this->redirect( array( 'action' => 'members'));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add member.');
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I apologize for such a long post for such a simple/annoyance problem but I hate having stuff like this in my applications/websites.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `'last' => false`? makes no sense to me.. if one didnt input any email there is no need to also check on a valid form of email...

Comment: Yea its unnecessary, I was just going over the documentation and was trying different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form will most likely be another form of post: put.

A quick explanation is:

```
POST is simulated by FormHelper for 'create' form, or any post form that isn't modifying an existing record.

PUT is for updating existing records.
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::create

Your add action counts as "create".

By the way: The cake code shows that it actually SHOULD be a POST (see comments below). So somewhere in your code you make the helper change it from POST to PUT there. Maybe you are doing some unconventional things.

Tip: If you want to be on the safe side, check on both:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {}
```

to make sure both post types are valid.

Also try to stick to conventions and use lower_case_underscored fieldnames. And last but not least drop the "id" validation. It's pointless to validate primary keys.

Comment: Awesome! that did the trick.... I feel pretty stupid lol. Spent hours on that. New to the framework and web development in general, I was familiar with POST and GET requests. Anyway, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Incorrect. Creating a new record is a POST, editing a record is a PUT. It's stated in the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::create) and apparent by the  bake [template](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default/actions/controller_actions.ctp#L54) code.

Comment: @Archon Why do you have a notEmpty validation for your id field? It would be empty when creating a new record.

Comment: For some reason it still had to be is(PUT) for his create/add action. So somewhere along the line Cake makes it a PUT request...

Comment: @Admad, my id field isn't auto increment. It is going to be a 9 digit student number and so will be used to uniquely identify the tuple as a student. I will have more validations on the id field, like a regular expression to make sure the student ID matches the conventions of the school (haven't looked into if cakePHP has a regular expressions rule built in, most likely it does.) So, please let me know if I am on the right track here.

Comment: @mark, any idea on how to find out where I might have forced it to do a PUT? I followed the Blog example to do everything so far so wouldn't know where I might have made some unconventional calls to the framework. I guess one thing that I am doing different is the id field which isn't auto incremented.

Comment: @Archon CakePHP officially only supports auto increment integers and uuid as primary key. If you use something else it's likely you will have issues with some of the model functions. I suggest you make the id field auto increment and use a separate field to store the student identifier as per you needs.